# CheckBox chamando button com ionic 2

Tags: ionic, ionic2

Estou simulando algo parecido com um carrinho de compras utilizando `ionic 2`. Basicamente você escreve o nome do item e o valor e vai criando uma lista com checkbox como na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu queria que a opção [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] só aparecesse ao selecionar uma das checkbox e não ficasse estático na tela como está agora. Como posso fazer isso?

**grid chamando as CheckBox:**

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of produto">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label (click)="clicou(item.desc)">
          {{ item.desc }} {{ item.valor }}
        </ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

**parte que seta o button no código:**

```
<button ion-button block (click)="remove()" color="danger" style="transition: none 0s ease 0s;">
    <span class="button-inner">
      <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
      Remover Selecionados
    </span>
    <div class="button-effect"></div>
  </button>
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: @Viana parte dele sim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione o `(ionChange)` chamando uma função e passando como parametro o `$event` e o `item`. Dentro da sua função será necessário carregar num vetor os itens selecionados e setar a a variavel `selecionado` como `true` para mostrar o botão. Após isso, é necessario tambem verificar se algum item foi deselecionado e é necessario tirar o item do vetor de itens selecionados. Se o vetor estiver totalmente vazio, ele seta o a variavel bool `selecionado` como `false` e então o botão some.

No seu componente.ts

```
export class componente {
  private produtos: any = [
    {nome: "sabao", valor: "10"},
    {nome: "miojo", valor: "12"},
    {nome: "pasta", valor: "15"},
    {nome: "cup nudes", valor: "14"}
  ]
  private itensSelecionados: any [] = [];
  private selecionado: boolean = false;
  constructor(){}

  datachanged(e:any, item: any){
    if(e.checked){
      for (let x = 0; x < this.produtos.length; x++) {
        if(this.produtos[x].nome == item.nome){
          this.itensSelecionados.push(item);
          this.selecionado = true;   
        }      
      }
    }
    else{
      for (let x = 0; x < this.itensSelecionados.length; x++) {
        if(this.itensSelecionados[x].nome == item.nome){
          this.itensSelecionados.splice(x,1);
          if(this.itensSelecionados.length == 0){
            this.selecionado = false;
            return false;
          }
        }        
      }
    }
  }
```

---

No seu grid.

---

```
    <ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of produtos">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>
          {{ item.nome }} {{ item.valor }}
        </ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox checked="false" (ionChange)="datachanged($event, item)"></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

---

No seu botão

---

```
 <ion-footer>
  <button *ngIf="selecionado" (click)="remove()" ion-button block color="danger" style="transition: none 0s ease 0s;">
    <span><ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>Remover Selecionados</span>
  </button>
</ion-footer>
```

Isso resolve o seu problema, basta ajustar o seu código.

Comment: Ola amigo, copiei e colei como voce fez mas o meu botão nao ta aparecendo quando seleciono a checkbox

Comment: qual a sua versão do angular?

Comment: 2. Eu peguei o que vc mandou e coloquei em cima do meu código antigo

Comment: poderia postar como está o seu .ts?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QBYyOY coloquei aqui só pra voce poder visualizar como está

Comment: conseguiu visualizar o codigo?

Comment: sim, consegui. Vou postar a solução mais a noite.

Comment: Ficarei no aguardo amigo!

Comment: Bom dia meu caro. Desculpe por não ter solucionado ontem, estive sobrecarregado. Editei a solução, da uma olhada. Agora certifico que essa funciona, pois testei aqui. Qualquer duvida me pergunte.

Comment: Não sei por que nao está funcionando. sou novato estou copiando e colando o que vc diz mas mesmo assim não funciona. agora ele simplesmente aparece produtos na lista e nao apaga

Comment: só copiar e colar realmente não vai funcionar. Eu alterei aqui de acordo com o seu código. Testa aí. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLbXEV

Comment: no seu ai ele realmente exclui o selecionado? mesmo com seu código aqui, ele só remove por ordem. O que adicionei primeiro vai excluindo e assim sucessivamente

Comment: bom.. a variavel itensSelecionados recebe os itens a serem excluidos da sua lista. A partir dessa variavel eu verifico se esta vazia (não mostra o botão excluir) e se tiver algo (mostra o botão excluir). Isso resolve o seu problema de mostrar ou não o botão de acordo com o seu checkbox.

Comment: O seu botão de excluir chama o metodo Remove(). Dentro da sua função remove vc precisa exlcuir os itens selecionados da sua variavel produto. Dentro dessa função, vc precisa verificar se há algo dentro da variavel itenselecionados e comparar se aquele item existe dentro de produto. Se existir, vc o elimina.

Comment: @hunterxhunter tudo certo ai?

Comment: @jrspante to tentando montar a condicao dentro remove() que vc comentou acima

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81601/discussion-between-jraspante-and-hunter-xhunter).